# Cannot push view controller using editActionsForRow

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I've encountered a problem while creating an iOS app. That's weird because I though it would be very easy to do.

I've got a TableView and editActionsForRowAt which returns one action. Clicking on it should navigate to my second ViewController which is loaded from .xib file. I know that this function is executed when clicking the button but the VC does not open.

MainViewController.swift

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let action = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "more") { (uiTableViewRowAction, indexPath) in

            let detailsVC = DetailsViewController(nibName: "DetailsViewController", bundle: nil)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsVC, animated: true)

        }

        return [action]
    }
```

DetailsViewController.swift (it's empty for now)

```
import UIKit

    class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

    }
```

I've called this pushViewController method multiple of times in the past so it makes me wonder why it doesn't show up. What's the problem?

edit:

`present` doesn't work either.

`present(detailsVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`
returns

`TableView[2646:125041] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "DetailsViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what was a problem but I deleted the DetailsVC .swift and .xib and created new one and above code works fine...